# Websphere manageprofile files don't exist in my current installation

Tags: websphere, missing-features

I have just downloaded and extracted Websphere locally in my computer and I can't find the manageprofiles command files (both .ssh and .bat). The version of Websphere is 8.5.5.4. Reading its documentation, it assumes that both files should be placed under the bin directory, but they are missing. I have also searched the web trying to download them manually, finding no answer.
Does anybody have any idea of what is happenning, and how may I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you "extracted" it and didn't "install" it, it's probably what's termed the "WebSphere Liberty Profile" and not the traditional application server profile.

"manageprofiles" is not used in Liberty.  If your instructions include it, you may need the traditional application server which is also available as a trial.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I thought it could be something related to the Liberty version

Answer (score 0):

As covener wrote `manageprofiles` is in traditional WAS. In Liberty just go to the `bin` folder and issue:

`server create yourServerName`

then start it using:

`server start yourServerName`

and you are good to go ;-)